# Assistance with vertical navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to create a vertical navigation in my HTML document, but I cannot seem to get the main menu to line up evenly. Here is my HTML for the vertical navigation:

```
 <div id="navbar">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Drop 3</a></li>
 </ul></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
 </ul></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
 </ul>

 </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#navbar {
margin-left: -40px; 
}

#navbar li{
list-style: none;
position: relative;
width: 209px;
padding: 6px;
line-height: 20pt;
cursor: pointer;
}

#navbar ul ul{
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: -28px;
visibility:hidden;
height: 100px;
}

#navbar ul li:hover ul{
visibility:visible;
}
```

This is my first post ever, so I apologize if I didn't post in the correct format. This code is also from a much larger HTML/CSS file, so I just copy/pasted the only part I'm having an issue with. If I need to post a screenshot of what I'm talking about I can do that.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Could you please also setup a minimal [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the issue?

Comment: Code as posted: http://jsfiddle.net/uab2hr50/

Comment: I think we might need a better description of what you want to see as an outcome. Welcome!

Comment: if you want to line up menu below [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uab2hr50/2/)

Comment: _If I need to post a screenshot of what I'm talking about I can do that._ Let's do that! Because _line up evenly_ could mean anything.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! As far as posting an image it says I cannot until I reach 10 reputation. Seeing as I'm new to this site forum I have no idea what it's asking. I will try using the information you all have provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/uab2hr50/2/

if you are looking to align the sub menu below the main menu

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#navbar ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
}
#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 209px;
  line-height: 20pt;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#navbar ul ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#navbar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop 3</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow I really like this! It works for the type of project I am working on. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome @WendyMorningstar :) do accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here preventing the display you expect:

## [First: the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uab2hr50/3/)

**CSS CHANGES**

```
#navbar li{
list-style: none;
position: relative;
/*width: 209px;*/
padding: 6px;
line-height: 20pt;
cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

#navbar li:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

#navbar ul a {
    display: inline-block;
}

#navbar ul ul{
margin-top: 0;
visibility:hidden;
height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: -9000px;
}

#navbar ul ul li:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

We removed quite a bit of your padding and margin rules here, and stopped setting a width on the `li` that you went ahead and broke out of anyway in the original code.

Then, we told both the `a` and `ul` elements to display as `inline-block`, told them they were to vertically align at the `top` and removed the `padding-top` off the first child of your sub-nav.

Then, we way over-compensate for the height of your lists by setting a `margin-bottom` of `-9000px` to pull your subsequent list items up to where they belong.

No absolute positioning needed, which would probably require some JavaScript to position everything reliably for you given different conditions.

Hope that helps.